# How to read ocsp package content in wireshark

Tags: networking, ssl, wireshark, openssl

I have deployed basic ocsp server from `OpenSSl Cookbook` by Ivan Ristic page 44 with following command:

```
openssl ocsp -port 9080 -index db/index -rsigner root-ocsp.crt -rkey private/root-ocsp.key -CA root-ca.crt -text
```

And I want to investigate ocsp request content to my server in Wireshark:

```
 openssl ocsp -issuer root-ca.crt -CAfile root-ca.crt -cert root-ocsp.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
```

with filter `port 9080` applied to loopback (device?) I get necessary tcp packages:

[image]

How to show their content in oscp format?

P.S. I cannot apply `oscp` filter, wireshark mark it with red.

Comment: Since this is a HTTP request which includes the OCSP request you have to use HTTP as the protocol to show the details. IMHO Wireshark then displays the OCSP request and response in the body of the request/response as long as they have the correct Content-Type set.

Comment: I have recorded transaction on image, when I write `http` to `Apply a display filter...` no packages is displayed, how I must set `HTTP as the protocol to show the details`?  [As you can see, content-type is present](http://i.imgur.com/yCoFU9i.png)

Comment: A display filter *filters* only, i.e. does not change *how* data are displayed but only *which* data are displayed. You have to change how the data are decoded instead. How this is done depends on the version of Wireshark. But for example `Analyze | Decode As` in current version.

Comment: Thanks, your answers had pushed me on right solution. It was very important for me

Answer (score 2):

In order to activate OCSP decoding, I had to activate HTTP decoding

Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> HTTP -> TCP Ports: add 9080